# Does my Wireless Charging PCB need to have FCC, UL, CSA, certified marks?

Tags: wireless, electromagnetic, fcc, wireless-charging, certification

I have a simple 5W output wireless charging device that uses a tx coil to transfer power to a phone, this is powered from a 1800mAh battery. Do I need any certifications for this?

Comment: Wireless charging -> unintentional RF emitter -> FCC. You're not plugging into a mains electrical outlet for power, so UL, CSA, etc are not going to be interested in your device.

Comment: Sorry, so I do need FCC?

Comment: If you bought it, it should have all the certifications needed. If you are making it then you should know what you need for the market or markets you are working in.

Comment: Are you planning on selling this device?

Comment: I’m planning on selling this.